# Selenium and multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, django, selenium, multiprocessing

In my django app I use selenium for crawling and parsing some html page. I tried to introduce the multiprocess to improve performance. This is my code:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from multiprocessing import Pool

os.environ["DISPLAY"]=":56017"

def render_js(url):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(300)
    driver.get(url)
    text = driver.page_source
    driver.quit()
    return text

def parsing(url):
    text = render_js(url)
    ... parsing the text ....
    ... write in db.... 


url_list = ['www.google.com','www.python.com','www.microsoft.com']
pool = Pool(processes=2)
pool.map_async(parsing, url_list)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

I have this error when two processes work together simultaneously and use selenium: the first process starts firefox with 'www.google.it' and it returns the correct text, the second with url 'www.python.com' returns the text of www.google.it and not of www.python.com.  Can you tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: You definitely don't need to use Selenium just to scrape the page for it's HTML - this is likely where your performance issue is - Selenium is unneeded for your job.

Comment: @Arran I have many page with javascript and selenium is the best solution that I know... If I use selenium with a single task  everything works perfectly with performance in line with other instruments. Now, however, the number of url is increasing a lot and would like to find a way to get more performance with multiprocessing... How can I do?

Comment: It appears your using Firefox in your tests. I'd suggest giving PhantomJS a try instead "Webdriver.PhantomJS"

Comment: you are trying to share the same instance with multiple processes.  You need to create a new instance for each process you create

Answer (score 3):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from multiprocessing import Pool

def parsing(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(300)
    driver.get(url)
    text = driver.page_source
    driver.close()
    return text

url_list = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.python.com']
pool = Pool(processes=4)
ret = pool.map(parsing, url_list)
for text in ret:
    print text[:30]
```

I tried running your code and Selenium complained about bad urls. Adding `http://` to it made it work.